# FastAPI sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I'm learning FastAPI and decided to write my first project. I got the error:

sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship ServiceVersion.servicekeyversion - there are no foreign keys linking these tables.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.

for:

service_model = models.Service()

models.py:

```
class Service(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'service'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name = Column(String, unique=True)

    serviceversion = relationship("ServiceVersion", back_populates='service_v')
    servicekey = relationship('ServiceKey', back_populates='service')


class ServiceVersion(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'serviceversion'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    service_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('service.id'))
    version = Column(String)
    is_used = Column(Boolean)
    
    service_v = relationship('Service', back_populates='serviceversion')
    servicekeyversion = relationship('ServiceKey', back_populates='serviceversion')


class ServiceKey(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'servicekey'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    service_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('service.id'))
    version_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('version.id'))
    service_key = Column(String)
    service_value = Column(String)

    service = relationship('Service', back_populates='servicekey')
    serviceversion = relationship('ServiceVersion', back_populates='servicekeyversion')
```

schemas.py:

```
class CreateService(BaseModel):
    name: str
    version: str
    is_used: bool
    keys: list[Key]

class Config:
    orm_mode = True
```

main.py:

```
async def post_service(service: CreateService, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    service_model = models.Service()
```

I think that there is some idea i didn't catch.

Comment: `servicekeyversion = relationship('ServiceKey', back_populates='version')` - which ForeignKey do you expect this relationship to use? There are no foreign keys that link anything to the `serviceversion`-table.

Comment: I suppose this is the way to implement ForeignKey version_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('version.id')). As I read I should add this to class ServiceVersion and version = relationship('ServiceVersion', back_populates='servicekeyversion') to class ServiceKey

Comment: i used code from https://github.com/codingwithroby/FastAPI-The-Complete-Course/blob/main/FastAPI-Alembic/models.py as a reference

Comment: But that `ForeignKey('version.id')` points to `version`, not `serviceversion`. Your table names does not match between the ForeignKey and the actual table name in your ServiceVersion model (`version` vs `serviceversion`).

Comment: @MatsLindh I edited code. Please check it. Is it what you mean? Error is the same

Comment: No, look at your ForeignKey: `version_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('version.id'))`. You tell it that the table name and column for linking `version` is `version.id`. But in your `ServiceVersion` class, you have defined it to be `serviceversion`, not `version`: `__tablename__ = 'serviceversion'`.

Comment: Silly me, you're rigth